# Magento 2 override framework class

Tags: magento2

We want to override Title.php of \vendor\magento\framework\View\Page We tried different ways but none of them are working. If anyone already did this before then please help us to do this.

Below is what we want to achieve.
Want to add static meta title to the entire website. If any other better way to do this then it will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to `di.xml` of your module

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\View\Page\Title" />
```

Then create the class  `[Vendor]\[Module]\View\Page\Title` that extends `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title` and make your changes in there